# Is there a way to use the less command in a while loop?

Tags: bash, syntax

I have this while loop that takes an input and creates a printf for each entry. This file is really big so having it print out will take forever. Is there a way I can save the result to a file and use `less` to have it be a paginated output?

```
while read line
do
            id=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <<< $line)
            ip=$(cut -d' ' -f2 <<< $line)
            mon=$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< $line)
            day=$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< $line)

            printf "%s 45%s (%s %s)\n" "$id" "$ip" "$mon" "$day"
done <<< "$inputFile"
```

I tried this

```
result+=$("%s 45%s (%s %s)\n" "$id" "$ip" "$mon" "$day")
```

and then just doing

```
less "$result"
```

outside the loop but that didn't work and I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Creating 4 subprocesses per line to run the `cut` command is very inefficient; `read` can do field splitting all by itself (`while read id ip mon day ignoredFields`; see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing)), but it'd be even faster to replace the entire loop with a single `awk` command: `awk '{printf "%s 45%s (%s %s)\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gordon said, this is a lot of pointless work, especially if the file is going to be big. Also `<<< "$inputFile"` implies the *entire text* of the file you said was so big has already been read into the `inputFile` variable, which seems pointless and counterproductive unless there's some specific reason?

Try something like this -

```
awk '{printf "%s 45%s (%s %s)\n", $1, $2, $3, $4}' file.in | less
```

or if you want the output saved in a file AND paginated to the screen,

```
awk '{ printf "%s 45%s (%s %s)\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }' file.in | tee out.txt | less
```

I also agree with Clint. The pagination should probably be separate - but since I haven't seen the whole structure, try a few and see what works.

Answer (score 1):

*nix is all about streaming tools. One tools streams to another. if you want to watch your script run using less you can just 'pipe' it...

write your script to a file - we'll call it "my.script.sh", make it executable "chmod +x my.script.sh" then use the | (pipe) operator...

```
./my.script.sh | less
```